# Problem handling Promises with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, promise

I have a small problem deleting with types. Here is my code snippet where I have the issue:

```
const prams = useParams<RouteParams>();
  const [event, setEvent] = useState<EventType>();
  const [error, setError] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  let id = prams.id;

  console.log(id);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    if (id) {
      getEventById(id)
        .then((res: EventType) => { // the issue is here it says is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown) => void | PromiseLike<void>'
          setEvent(res);
          console.log(res, "rs");
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setError(true);
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
  }, [id]);

  console.log(event, "events");
```

When I replace `Event` with `any` it works fine.

the function for request the Event

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Config, URL } from "./Api";

const getEventById = async (id: string) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`${URL}getEvent/${id}`, Config);
  return Object.values(data?.event)[0];
};

export { getEventById };
```

Here is the Event Type:

```
export type EventType = {
  ADDRESS: string;
  EVENT_DATE: string;
  ID: string;
  MIN_PRICE: number;
  NAME: string;
  PICTURE: string;
  PLACE: string;
  PREVIEW: string;
  REGISTRATION_END_DATE: string;
  TYPE: string;
  DESCRIPTION: string;
  RESTAURANT_LOGO: string;
  RESTAURANT_ID?: string;
};
```

and here is the response from the `getEventById()`:

[image]

Any clue where the problem is, or maybe the solution?

Comment: Please give an [mre] - what's the actual error? Don't post screenshots.

Comment: Most likley, `getEventById` does not return `Promise<Event>`.

Comment: What is the definition of `getEventById`?

Comment: Please never post images instead of code, how should we copy the code to answer to edit it? How shall google crawl its content to help others?

Comment: I updated my question, sorry for making  bad format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your `getEventById` doesn't declare a proper return type, so it does not return a `Promise<Event>` but a `Promise<any>` because there is no way, the TS compiler can infer the correct type.

The simplest would probably be

```
const getEventById = async (id: string): Promise<Event> => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`${URL}getEvent/${id}`, Config);
  return Object.values(data?.event)[0];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `Event` is representing the Keyboard event. You need a different interface relevant to the response from the service. Try renaming it and see if you are importing the right interface

Comment: From where do you infer the `Event` is a Keyboard event?

Comment: the `Event` is type that I declared, you can check the question again I updated